# How to combine two dynamic sql with union ALL

Tags: sql-server

I have two dynamic sql queries like this

```
@sql = 'select productname,year from products'


@sql2 = 'select productname,year from products_sample'
```

I need something like this

```
select @query= (@SQL+'UNION ALL' +@SQL1 )
```

but it's not working

Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
declare  @SQL varchar(200)
declare @sql2 varchar(200)
declare @sqlresult varchar(200)
set @SQL = 'select productname,year from Products'

set @sql2 = 'select productname,year from products_sample'
set @sqlresult=@SQL+' UNION ALL ' +@sql2
exec @sqlresult
```

Comment: Would need to be `exec (@sqlresult)`. Without parentheses SQL Server will look for a stored procedure called `select productname,year from Products UNION ALL select productname,year from products_sample` rather than execute the string itself.

Answer (score 4):

As the queries are not parameterised at all you can also simply use

```
EXEC (@SQL + ' UNION ALL ' +  @SQL1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@sql = 'select productname,year from products'

@sql2 = 'select productname,year from products_sample'

sp_executeSQL @SQL+' UNION ALL ' +@SQL1
```

Comment: Needs to be `EXEC sp_executeSQL`. `EXEC` is only optional for the first statement in the batch. Also can't concatenate in the stored procedure parameter list itself.

Comment: Well it would be more useful to show working code. Also don't use parentheses in the stored procedure parameter list. Should be `sp_executesql` to work on a case sensitive collation and the variables you are concatenating have different names then the ones assigned above.